# Is that possible to read/parse elasticsearch index file directly?

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, lucene, apache-flink

The problem is that we have encountered a scenario where we want to directly read/load all data of an es index file into the memory, rather than using the scroll polling query method of the es api.

The reason we do this is that， by this way, it will not slowdown the performance of our es instance which using by other applications. This is very important for us.

After loading the index data into the memory, we can parse and transfer them to other big data applications, such as the kafka, flink directly.

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than 10000 records to read, the best way is by using the Scroll API. You can all the data using this API and store everything in memory if it fits.

I'm curious though about

> it will not slowdown the performance of our es instance which using by other applications.

Why do you think that using the standard API will be slow?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. 

My colleague maintain the Es instance,  and I need to read all index data from the es0_data/nodes/0/indices/ folder one by one , e.g., DylzKdjSqweNU9ZWRhkm4w, without query conditions and then saving them into kafka.


The problem is that the index files are network flow logs and each of which usually has very huge size.
Because the Es instance support for very important applications and my colleague think if I use standard Es API, i.e.scroll, it may increase burden on the Es instance and even maybe make the Es instance crash.

Comment: No. Scroll API is designed for that.